# Matlab - bsxfun no longer faster than repmat?

Tags: arrays, matlab, bsxfun

I'm trying to find the fastest way of standardizing a matrix in Matlab (zero mean, unit variance columns). It all comes down to which is the quickest way of applying the same operation to all rows in a matrix. Every post I've read come to the same conclusion: ***use bsxfun instead of repmat***. 
This article, written by Mathworks is an example: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/

However, when trying this on my own computer repmat is always quicker. Here are my results using the same code as in the article:

```
m = 1e5;
n = 100;
A = rand(m,n);

frepmat = @() A - repmat(mean(A),size(A,1),1);
timeit(frepmat)

fbsxfun = @() bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A));
timeit(fbsxfun)
```

Results:

```
ans =

    0.0349


ans =

    0.0391
```

In fact, I can never get bsxfun to perform better than repmat in this situation no matter how small or large the input matrix is.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: For me the bsxfun approach is always faster, also for bigger arrays. (Matlab 2014a)

Comment: For me (R2014b) bsxfun wins as well. What version of matlab do you use?

Comment: I've tried it on both 2014a and 2014b. Could the OS used make a difference? I'm on OSX.

Comment: OS X - R2014a: I can reproduce the results. Maybe the JIT Compiler has become more clever in the current version... You should still go with `bsxfun` though...

Comment: In recent versions of MATLAB, `repmat` is a compiled function like `bsxfun` while it was an m-file in previous versions, so I expect a performance boost for it.  On my system, there is equal performance to slightly better performance from `bsxfun` using your sample code (the difference is "in the wash" as I say).  However, `bsxfun` still has the advantage of not allocating an extra array into memory.

Comment: @knedlsepp: I guess not since I've tried both a and b. But maybe OSX is the key?

Comment: `bsxfun` is always better. No matter how long it takes :-P

Comment: I'm running Mac OS Mavericks with MATLAB R2013a.  My timings are `0.0574` for `repmat` and `0.0288` for `bsxfun`.  I can't reproduce your results.  As such, I don't think it's an operating system issue.  However, if we have to debate, I would choose `bsxfun` as well simply for readability and that you don't have to allocate any extra memory.  It could be a variety of things that make the timing equal.  It might be due to context switching of different programs.  Do you have a lot of programs open right now?  Did you also try doing a fresh reboot and running the tests again?

Comment: I can replicate the OP's results on OS X using a version I can't talk about. That article was written in 2008. `repmat` was nothing more than a regular M-file at the time. You can can still find this original M-code in current installs: type `edit toolbox/matlab/elmat/+matlab/+internal/+builtinhelper/repmat` in your command window. Many functions that started out as M-files have been turned into compiled native files over the years. Others have benefited from speedups due to recompilation for more modern hardware, better/newer libraries, and improved algorithms.

Comment: Win7-x64, `R2013b (repmat=0.0388, bsxfun=0.0368)` and `R2014b (repmat=0.0405, bsxfun=0.0372)`

Comment: To those timing, I recommend trying larger matrices, e.g., `m=1e5;` `n=1e3;` `A=rand(m,n);` at least.

Comment: @user89161: more likely it comes down to memory and cache. To do truly fair comparisons of this type across computers and OSes, we need to know about the CPUs involved, RAM, etc.

Comment: On the GPU (Tesla K20c/WIN64/R2014b), `bsxfun` is faster - with `m = 1e6`, I see 0.029 for `repmat` and `0.024` for `bsxfun`.

Comment: @user89161 Since it happens consistently, can you post results switching the order of the call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the advice you're reading, including the blog post from Loren, likely refers to old versions of MATLAB, for which `bsxfun` was quite a bit faster than `repmat`. In [R2013b](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#R2013b) (see the "Performance" section in the link), `repmat` was reimplemented to give large performance improvements when applied to numeric, char and logical arguments. In recent versions, it can be about the same speed as `bsxfun`.

For what it's worth, on my machine with R2014a I get

```
m = 1e5;
n = 100;
A = rand(m,n);

frepmat = @() A - repmat(mean(A),size(A,1),1);
timeit(frepmat)

fbsxfun = @() bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A));
timeit(fbsxfun)

ans =
      0.03756
ans =
     0.034831
```

so it looks like `bsxfun` is still a tiny bit faster, but not much - and on your machine it seems the reverse is the case. Of course, these results are likely to vary again, if you vary the size of `A` or the operation you're applying.

There may still be other reasons to prefer one solution over the other, such as elegance (I prefer `bsxfun`, if possible).

---

**Edit**: commenters have asked for a specific reason to prefer `bsxfun`, implying that it might use less memory than `repmat` by avoiding a temporary copy that `repmat` does not.

I don't think this is actually the case. For example, open Task Manager (or the equivalent on Linux/Mac), watch the memory levels, and type:

```
>> m = 1e5; n = 8e3; A = rand(m,n);
>> B = A - repmat(mean(A),size(A,1),1);
>> clear B
>> C = bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A));
>> clear C
```

(Adjust `m` and `n` until the jumps are visible in the graph, but not so big you run out of memory).

I see exactly the same behaviour from both `repmat` and `bsxfun`, which is that memory rises smoothly to the new level (basically double the size of `A`) with no temporary additional peak.

This is also the case even if the operation is done in-place. Again, watch the memory and type:

```
>> m = 1e5; n = 8e3; A = rand(m,n);
>> A = A - repmat(mean(A),size(A,1),1);
>> clear all
>> m = 1e5; n = 8e3; A = rand(m,n);
>> A = bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A));
```

Again, I see exactly the same behaviour from both `repmat` and `bsxfun`, which is that memory rises to a peak (basically double the size of `A`), and then falls back to the previous level.

So I'm afraid I can't see much technical difference in terms of either speed or memory between `repmat` and `bsxfun`. My preference for `bsxfun` is really just a personal preference as it feels a bit more elegant.

Comment: `bsxfun` still has the advantage of using up less memory, as it internally avoids data repetition, am I correct? I mean, give a reason to justify preference for `bsxfun`! :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo is it possible the re-implementation of `repmat` avoids the explicit memory copy? Is it possible it implements a "lazy" copy? I do not have access to recent Matlab versions...

Comment: @Shai Yes, that's what I meant with my question. It could be that `repmat` internally does some kind of optimization. I don't know. But I still prefer `bsxfun`!

Comment: @SamRoberts Thanks. Yes, I get the same behaviour here regarding memory. On the other hand, as for running time, `bsxfun` seems to be faster; [see Divakar's tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat)

Comment: @SamRoberts And now there's more! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800560/bsxfun-on-memory-efficiency-with-relational-operations