# Condition for columns based on same index as vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get a logical matrix as a result of a condition that is specific for each column `M(:,i)` of the original matrix, based on the value of the same index `i` in vector `N`, that is, `N(i)`.

I have looked this up online, but can't find anything quite like it. There must be a simple and clean way of doing this.

```
M =

     3    -1   100     8
   200     2   300     4
   -10     0     0   400

N =

     4     0    90     7
```

and my desired solution is, for each column of `M(:,i)`, the values less than `N(i)`:

```
     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     1     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a standard use-case for `bsxfun`:

```
O = bsxfun(@lt, M, N)
```

Here `@lt` is calling the "less than" function, i.e. it is the function handle to the `<` operator. `bsxfun` will then "expand" `N` along its singleton dimension by applying the function `@lt` to each row of `M` and the whole of `N`.

Note that you can easily achieve the same thing using a `for`-loop:

```
O = zeros(size(M));
for row = 1:size(M,1)
    O(row,:) = M(row,:) < N;
end
```

Or by using `repmat`:

```
O = M < repmat(N, size(M,1), 1);
```

but in MATLAB the `bsxfun` is usually the most efficient.

Comment: `bsxfun` is especially more efficient when working with relational operations - [`BSXFUN on memory efficiency with relational operations`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800560/bsxfun-on-memory-efficiency-with-relational-operations). Just one of the best cases really.

Comment: I learned more than the answer to the question there, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Possible two-line solution using `arrayfun` to apply the comparison to each column and index pair:

```
T = arrayfun(@(jj)M(:,jj) < N(jj), 1:numel(N), 'UniformOutput', false);
result = cat(2,T{:});
```

Edit: Of course, the bsxfun solution is much more efficient.