# Apply 2D threshold to 3D array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, threshold, temperature

With a geographical grid the size 20x30, I have two (temperature) variables:

The data `A` with the size 20x30x100
and a `threshold` the size 20x30

I'd like to apply the threshold to the data, i.e. to cut out the values in `A` that are above `threshold`, with every grid point having its own threshold. Since that will give a different number of values for each grid point, I thought to pad the rest with zeros, so that the resulting variable, let's call it `B`, will also be of the size 20x30x100.

I was thinking to do something like this, but there's something wrong with the loop:

```
B = sort(A,3); %// sort third dimension in ascending order
threshold_3d = repmat(threshold,1,1,100); %// make threshold into same size as B

for i=1:20
    for j=1:30
        if B(i,j,:) > threshold_3d(i,j,:); %// if B is above threshold
          B(i,j,:); %// keep values
        else
          B(i,j,:) = 0; %// otherwise set to zero
        end
    end
end
```

What is the correct way to do the loop?
What other options to do this are there?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for a much more efficient solution which will internally take care of the replication being done with `repmat`, like so -

```
B = bsxfun(@times,B,bsxfun(@gt,B,threshold))
```

A more efficient solution might be to use [`logical indexing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) to set the `False` elements from the mask created by `bsxfun(gt`, i.e. `True` ones with the use of `bsxfun(@le` in `B` to zeros thereby avoiding the use of `bsxfun(@times`, which for huge multidimensional arrays could be a *bit expensive*, like so -

```
B(bsxfun(@le,B,threshold)) = 0
```

**`Note on efficiency :`** Being a relational operation, going with the vectorized operation with `bsxfun` would provide both memory and runtime efficiency. The memory efficiency part has been discussed here - [`BSXFUN on memory efficiency with relational operations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800560/bsxfun-on-memory-efficiency-with-relational-operations) and the performance numbers have been researched here - [`Comparing BSXFUN and REPMAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat).

Sample run -

```
 >> B
 B(:,:,1) =
      8     3     9
      2     8     3
 B(:,:,2) =
      4     1     8
      4     5     6
 B(:,:,3) =
      4     8     5
      5     6     5
 >> threshold
 threshold =
      1     3     9
      1     9     1
 >> B(bsxfun(@le,B,threshold)) = 0
 B(:,:,1) =
      8     0     0
      2     0     3
 B(:,:,2) =
      4     0     0
      4     0     6
 B(:,:,3) =
      4     8     0
      5     0     5
```